# Why doesn't the element in my set get removed?

Tags: c++, set

```
map<int,int> distance;
map<int,int> previous;

map<int,int>::iterator distIt;
map<int,int>::iterator prevIt;

set<int> nodes;

[..removed..]

it = topo.begin();
while(it != topo.end())
{
    distance[it->first] = 9999;
    previous[it->first] = 9999;
    nodes.insert(it->first);
    cout << "Processed: " << it->first << endl;
    it++;
}

distance[source] = 0;

while(!nodes.empty())
{
    distIt = min_element(distance.begin(), distance.end());
    int node = distIt->first;
    cout << "MIN: " << distIt->first << "|wtih cost|" << distIt->second << endl;
    nodes.erase(node);
    cin.get();
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Processed: 1
Processed: 1
Processed: 2
Processed: 2
Processed: 2
Processed: 3
Processed: 4
Processed: 4
Processed: 5
Processed: 5
MIN: 1|wtih cost|0

MIN: 1|wtih cost|0

MIN: 1|wtih cost|0
```

So, why can't I `erase(node)` here?

**Edit:** SSCCE here:  http://ideone.com/EQ7BHt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop you look for the minimum element in `distance` and then erase the key you find in `nodes`. The erasing does not alter `distance`, because it is a completely different container. Therefore the next loop passes will give you the same element in `distance`, and the `erase` call on `nodes` will have no effect because you removed the number the first time already.

In other words: you have to remove the element you found from `distance` as well, or else you will always find the same minimum and never get to remove the remaining elements from `nodes`.

Answer (score -2):

Use `node.delete(node)` and try again.

Comment: `.delete()` isn't a member of `std::set`

Comment: Nor it it a member of `int`, which is the type of `node`.